# Se eu vou criar um aplicação J2EE no Eclipse, devo baixar a versão JavaEE?

Tags: java, java-ee, eclipse

Qual é a versão do Eclipse mais adequada para trabalhar com J2EE?

Comment: Sim deve! existem outras opções também.

Comment: Ok. valeu. Pq me negativaram?

Comment: Acho que é pq a pergunta está meio estranha? esse tipo de pergunta vc fazer no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *"A plataforma era conhecida como Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition ou J2EE até o nome ser alterado para Java Platform, Enterprise Edition ou Java EE na versão 5. A versão atual é chamada Java EE 7."* fonte [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Nomenclatura_e_Hist.C3.B3rico_de_vers.C3.B5es)

Comment: Na página de [download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) tem a descrição contendo quais ferramentas estão incluídas em cada versão.

Comment: @rray Achei a pergunta bastante válida. Estava escrita de forma estranha, mas é uma questão objetiva e que sempre causa confusão mesmo.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida aquele comentário se refere a primeira versão da pergunta.

Comment: @rray  Sim, compreendo. Fui eu quem editou a pergunta. Só quis dizer que acho que não é uma pergunta só pro chat.